# Room/LiveData code executes fine inside of a Button listener, but crashes in the `onCreate` method

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

For a pixel art app I am making I have the following code (I know, it's not the best):

```
lateinit var currentPixelArtsObj: PixelArts
lateinit var pixelData: List<Pixel>
var pixelDataAsViews = mutableListOf<View>()

fun CanvasActivity.extendedOnCreate() {
    spanCount = intent.getIntExtra(StringValues.SPAN_COUNT_EXTRA, spanCount)
    index = intent.getIntExtra(StringValues.INDEX_EXTRA, -1)

    if (index != -1) {
        AppData.db.pixelArtCreationsDao().getAllPixelArtCreations().observe(context, {
            currentPixelArtsObj = it[index!!]

                pixelData = JsonConverter.convertJsonStringToListOfView(currentPixelArtsObj.pixelData)
                spanCount = sqrt(pixelData.size.toDouble()).toInt()

                for (data in pixelData) {
                    val view = View(context)

                    if (data.pixelColor != null) view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#" + Integer.toHexString(data.pixelColor)))
                    pixelDataAsViews.add(view)
                }

                extendedSetUpFragment()

                data.forEach { data_it ->
                    val index = data.indexOf(data_it)

                    if (pixelDataAsViews[index].background != null) data_it.setBackgroundColor((pixelDataAsViews[index].background as ColorDrawable).color)
                }
                canvasFragmentInstance.modifyPixels(data)
            
        })

    } else {
        setUpFragment()
    }

    setBindings()
    setUpRecyclerView()
    setOnClickListeners()
    setColours()

    binding.colorPickerFragmentHost.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    binding.activityCanvasCanvasTitleEditText.setText(intent.getStringExtra("PROJECT_TITLE"))
}
```

As you can see, it retrieves the appropriate `PixelArts` object from Room and converts the `List<Pixel>` to a `List<View>` which will then be displayed on the screen for the user.

I'm having issues with the following block of code which performs the conversion:

```
    data.forEach { data_it ->
                    val index = data.indexOf(data_it)

                    if (pixelDataAsViews[index].background != null) data_it.setBackgroundColor((pixelDataAsViews[index].background as ColorDrawable).color)
                }
                canvasFragmentInstance.modifyPixels(data)
```

The problem is, whenever I run this code from my `onCreate` method, I get the following exception (which I presume has something to do with `LiveData` though I'm not 100% sure):

```
2021-12-05 04:35:36.502 10331-10331/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose, PID: 10331
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.fragments.CanvasFragment.getBinding(CanvasFragment.kt:19)
        at com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.fragments.CanvasFragment.modifyPixels(CanvasFragment.kt:49)
        at com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.activities.canvas.CanvasActivity_onCreateKt.extendedOnCreate$lambda-1(CanvasActivity+onCreate.kt:47)
        at com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.activities.canvas.CanvasActivity_onCreateKt.$r8$lambda$9V-5-tVaAUBXX5T7oUXd3NzQT_4(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.activities.canvas.CanvasActivity_onCreateKt$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onChanged(Unknown Source:4)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:133)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:151)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:309)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$1.run(LiveData.java:93)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

The weird think is, whenever I extract the code to a listener, such as the following:

```
binding.eraseButton.setOnClickListener {
        isErasing = !isErasing

        data.forEach { data_it ->
            val index = data.indexOf(data_it)

            if (pixelDataAsViews[index].background != null) data_it.setBackgroundColor((pixelDataAsViews[index].background as ColorDrawable).color)
        }
        canvasFragmentInstance.modifyPixels(data)
    }
```

... and then press the button - the code functions just fine without any exceptions!

I have absolutely no clue why this is happening, I am a noob to all this `LiveData` and `Room` stuff, just so you guys know!

Sometimes I come across very strange glitches/errors in code, and this is probably the strangest I've come across. I've tried for 6-7 hours to fix it but I've had no luck unfortunately.

Here is some more code that I can provide which might be of use:

**Model:**

```
package com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.models

import androidx.room.*
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

@Entity
data class PixelArts(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_bitmap") var bitmap: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_title") var title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_pixel_data") var pixelData: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_favourited") var favourited: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_date_created") var dateCreated: String = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").format(LocalDateTime.now())) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var objId = 0
}
```

**DAO:**

```
@Dao
interface PixelArtCreationsDao {
    @Insert
    suspend fun insertPixelArt(pixelArt: PixelArts)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM PixelArts ")
    fun getAllPixelArtCreations(): LiveData<List<PixelArts>>

    @Query("DELETE FROM PixelArts WHERE objId=:pixelArtId")
    fun deletePixelArtCreation(pixelArtId: Int)

    @Query("UPDATE PixelArts SET item_pixel_data=:pixelData AND item_bitmap=:bitmap WHERE objId=:pixelArtId")
    fun updatePixelArtCreation(pixelArtId: Int, bitmap: String, pixelData: String)
}
```

**Database:**

```
@Database(entities = [PixelArts::class], version = 1)
abstract class PixelArtDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun pixelArtCreationsDao(): PixelArtCreationsDao

    companion object {
        var instance: PixelArtDatabase? = null
        fun getDatabase(context: Context): PixelArtDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                synchronized(PixelArtDatabase::class) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        PixelArtDatabase::class.java,
                        AppData.dbFileName).allowMainThreadQueries().build()
                }
            }
            return instance!!
        }
    }
}
```

**AppData:**

```
class AppData {
    companion object {
        var dbFileName = "pixel_art_db"
        lateinit var db: PixelArtDatabase
    }
}
```

---

Somebody asked where `extendedOnCreate` is called - here is where:

```
class CanvasActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CanvasFragmentListener, ColorPickerListener, ColorPickerFragmentListener, FindAndReplaceFragmentListener {

    var previousView: View? = null

    val context = this

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        extendedOnCreate()
    }
...
```

Comment: where you initialise your CanvasFragment object cause error suggest that you're trying to access CanvaseFragment instance without initialising it.

Comment: Probably you are trying to access views at a stage of the fragment lifecycle where it is not attached to an activity. When you put the code in a button listener it always works because a button cannot be pressed if it isn’t attached to an activity so it is always pressed at a safe stage of the lifecycle. Can you show the context of where you call `extendedOnCreate()`? It is highly unusual for an extension function of an activity to be accessing what would normally/properly be private functions and properties of your activity. (Those last four function calls and `binding`.

Comment: By the way, your database singleton getter isn’t 100% threadsafe. If two threads call it for the first time close to simultaneously they could both get different instances because one would wait for synchronization while the other gets it’s instance, and then when it enters the synchronization block it causes another one to be created and assigned. You need a secondary if-null check inside the synchronization block.

Comment: @Bhavin `CanvasFragment` is actually initialized, it gets initialized in the `extendedSetUpFragment` method.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Ok, how can I make it so it is executed at a safe stage in the lifecycle, cause I'm a noob and I don't 100% get this.

Comment: @Tenfour04 the code is from a Udemy tutorial, I will fix it.

Comment: I'm not seeing where `canvasFragmentInstance` is defined or how it is created. Your CanvasActivity doesn't seem to have any views or fragments added to it at all. Also, is your first block of code defined at the top level, outside any class? If so, you have some global (aka static) properties, which you must be extremely careful with on Android. If you're going to use statics, you need a very thorough understanding of the various Android lifecycles to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I actually moved the code to the Fragment rather than the Activity and it works fine. Thanks though!